# Unable to retrieve emails from Gmail using Java

Tags: java, gmail, jakarta-mail

I am trying to write a simple program in Java, in order to check my mailbox and get whatever email is in the inbox.

I have read various tutorials and watched a video in youtube and I found out that most people do something similar to [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javamail_api/javamail_api_checking_emails.htm)

So the I have taken the code found there:

```
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class CheckingMails {

   public static void check(String host, String storeType, String user,
      String password) 
   {
      try {
      //create properties field
      Properties properties = new Properties();
      properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
      properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
      Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
      //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
      Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3");
      store.connect(host, user, password);
      //create the folder object and open it
      Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
      emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY); 
      // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
      Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
      System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);
      for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
         Message message = messages[i];
         System.out.println("---------------------------------");
         System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
         System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
         System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
         System.out.println("Text: " + message.getContent().toString());
      }
      //close the store and folder objects
      emailFolder.close(false);
      store.close();
      } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (MessagingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      String host = "pop.gmail.com";// change accordingly
      String mailStoreType = "pop3";
      String username = "giannisthedrummer2@gmail.com";// change accordingly
      String password = "********";// change accordingly
      check(host, mailStoreType, username, password);
   } 
}
```

But I can't get my mails. Instead this error appears:

```
javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: EOF on socket
at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:104)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:233)
at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:134)
at CheckingMails.check(CheckingMails.java:29)
at CheckingMails.main(CheckingMails.java:69)
```

I have enabled the POP and IMAP accesibility features on my email, as well as enabled less secure connections.

I downloaded the necessary .jar files from [mail.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/m/Downloadmailjar.htm) and [activation.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/a/Downloadactivationjar.htm)

After looking around a bit, I found out that the issue probably is coming from Google's side, meaning that the authentication is going worng. The password and the name is correct (I have checked that multiple times). I have enabled both IMAP and POP connections and I have allowed less secure connections, but still I get an `javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException` error.

Any ideas why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're connecting on the SSL port but not enabling SSL.  Follow the [Gmail instructions in the JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmail).  Get rid of the port setting and set `mail.pop3.ssl.enable`.

And make sure you understand the limitations of pop3 vs. imap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

According to your suggestion, I need to change my properties, like this:

`properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
      properties.put("mail.pop3.user", user);
      //properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
      properties.setProperty("mail.pop3.ssl.enable", "true");
`
Right? Because if that is the case I get another error. Can you maybe provide me with an example of how the properties should look like, or what am I doing wrong apart from the SSL. I had in mind that it shoul be there, but then the error looks more complicated.

Comment: There's an example in the FAQ.  If it's not working for you, update your original post with the current code you're using and add the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug).  If you're getting a different error now, create a new post.

Comment: After applying your advice, I searched around for the new error and I found the solution. There was an issue with the ssl certificate. I was missing basically one property. I will post the answer bellow. Thank you very much for your help and for building the library in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

do below change to your Gmail account to access it from outside

1. Login to Gmail.
2. Access the URL as https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps
3. Select "Turn on"

Comment: Can anyone try out this code, with their own credentials? Am I missing something, when I set the properties?

Answer (score 0):

For the people that will struggle in the future in the same way I did:

After applying the suggestion from [Bill Shannon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1040885/bill-shannon), I got another error,which I found out that it was coming due to the fact that I hadn't configure the ssl certificates properly. Since I have little to no clue about those, I was searching around the internet to find

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
  properties.put("mail.imap.host", host);
  properties.put("mail.imap.user", user);
  properties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
  properties.put("mail.imap.ssl.trust", "*");
```

I changed the pop3 protocol to IMAP, because the later allows me to perform more tasks, but for the sole purpose of retrieving my emails both work in the same way.

The last line, in my understanding will accept any certificate, which probably is not the right way to go about it, but at the moment I don't know which one is the correct one.

Thank you all for your help.

****** It is important that the user, enables the POP3/IMAP connections in their accounts and also turn on the less secure applications, as it was stated previously. ******

Comment: Normally, the JDK contains the root certificates that allow public web sites such as Gmail to be validated properly.  Trusting all certificates defeats that validation and likely points to another configuration problem.  And of course weakens your security.  In some cases, a firewall or anti-virus product will interpose on the communication and will present its own certificate instead of the Gmail certificate.  This creates a man-in-the-middle situation that may be intended, but should be evaluated carefully.  See the [JavaMail FAQ](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#installcert) for more.

Comment: You are right. I uninstalled the JDK and reinstalled it and now that line is no longer necessary. But I find that very weird. Thank you very much for your help.